# Is this expression bounded when $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ is prime and $t \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.

The problem under consideration is as in the title:

> Is the following expression bounded when $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ is prime and $t \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?
> $$\dfrac{\sigma\bigg(p^{\dfrac{t-1}{2}}\bigg)\sigma\bigg(p^{\dfrac{t+1}{2}}\bigg)}{\sigma(p^t)} - 1$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

First, the following expression
$$\sigma\bigg(p^{\dfrac{t-1}{2}}\bigg)\sigma\bigg(p^{\dfrac{t+1}{2}}\bigg) - \sigma(p^t)$$
can be rewritten as
$$\dfrac{p\bigg(p^{\dfrac{t-1}{2}} - 1\bigg)\bigg(p^{\dfrac{t+1}{2}} - 1\bigg)}{\bigg(p-1\bigg)^2}.$$
Dividing through by $\sigma(p^t)$, we get
$$\dfrac{\sigma\bigg(p^{\dfrac{t-1}{2}}\bigg)\sigma\bigg(p^{\dfrac{t+1}{2}}\bigg)}{\sigma(p^t)} - 1 = \dfrac{p\bigg(p^{\dfrac{t-1}{2}} - 1\bigg)\bigg(p^{\dfrac{t+1}{2}} - 1\bigg)}{\bigg(p^{t+1} - 1\bigg)\bigg(p-1\bigg)}.$$

Since $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ is prime and $t \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ is an integer, then it is evident that
$$f(p,t) := \dfrac{p\bigg(p^{\dfrac{t-1}{2}} - 1\bigg)\bigg(p^{\dfrac{t+1}{2}} - 1\bigg)}{\bigg(p^{t+1} - 1\bigg)\bigg(p-1\bigg)} > 0.$$

It remains to find an upper bound.  I claim that:

> **CLAIM** $f(p,t) < 1$

*Proof Attempt* Suppose to the contrary that $f(p,t) \geq 1$.

Then we obtain

$$p^{t+2} - p^{t+1} - p + 1 = \bigg(p^{t+1} - 1\bigg)\bigg(p-1\bigg) \leq p\bigg(p^{\dfrac{t-1}{2}} - 1\bigg)\bigg(p^{\dfrac{t+1}{2}} - 1\bigg) = p^{t+1} - p^{\dfrac{t+3}{2}} - p^{\dfrac{t+1}{2}} + p,$$
which leads to a contradiction.

Hence, we have
$$0 < \dfrac{p\bigg(p^{\dfrac{t-1}{2}} - 1\bigg)\bigg(p^{\dfrac{t+1}{2}} - 1\bigg)}{\bigg(p^{t+1} - 1\bigg)\bigg(p-1\bigg)} < 1$$
and the expression in question is bounded.

Here are my:

**QUESTIONS**

> **(1)** Is my proof attempt valid?  If not, how can it be mended to produce a correct demonstration?

> **(2)** Would it be possible to improve on the lower and upper bounds obtained for $f(p,t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)**

Yes. (We have $0\color{red}{\le}f(p,t)$ if $t\ge 1$.)

**(2)**

We have
$$\frac{\partial f(p,t)}{\partial t}=\frac{(p + 1) p^{(t + 1)/2}(p^{(t+1)/2}-1)^2  \log p}{2 (p - 1) (p^{t + 1} - 1)^2}\gt 0$$
and
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}f(p,t)=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{p\bigg(1-p^{-(t-1)/2}\bigg)\bigg(1-p^{-(t+1)/2}\bigg)}{\bigg(p-p^{-t}\bigg)(p-1)}=\frac{1}{p-1}$$

So, if $t\ge 1$, then we obtain
$$0=f(p,1)\le f(p,t)\lt \frac{1}{p-1}$$
to conclude
$$\color{red}{0\le f(p,t)\lt \frac 14}$$

Comment: Thank you for this answer, @mathlove!  =)